# rails_admin how to exclude actions in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin for the first time  and needed to create a new action for one of my models.
This is what I added to initializer.rails_admin.rb:

```
config.model Movie do
   ...
   ....    
   config.actions do
     collection :top_five do
        action_name :top_five
    end
  end
end
```

I thought this would create a new action for my Movie model, but  it is present as an option (tab) for all models.
How can I make it to appear only in one model?

Thank you!
Fernanda

Answer (score 0):

The only clean way I know of that currently allows this is by using CanCan for authorization, described in the RailsAdmin documentation [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan).

You may also override rails_admin views to show the tab only for the specific model, but that's not quite as clean.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for everyone else landing here, here is my solution:

```
config.actions do
  ...
  show_in_app
  collection :top_five do
    only ['Movie']
    i18n_key :top_five
  end
  ...
end
```

This has been added to the [documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions#per-model-basis)